# Python / Tweepy: skip tweet that has already been liked

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I'm currently trying to create a simple like bot for twitter and I have the problem that I keep getting
"403 Forbidden
139 - You have already favorited this status."

I've added an if query so that it skips tweets that have already been liked, but I keep getting the 139 error - what am I doing wrong?

```
search = "python" 
nrTweets = 20

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, search).items(nrTweets):
    try:
        if not tweet.favorited:
            tweet.favorite()
            print('Tweet Liked')
            time.sleep(60)
        else:
            continue
    except tweepy.TweepyException as e:
        print(e)
```

Example result:

```
Tweet Liked
Tweet Liked
Tweet Liked
Tweet Liked
403 Forbidden
139 - You have already favorited this status.
```

Comment: What did you try to debug that? Did you print the tweet's id to look at the tweet on Twitter and check if 1. It is indeed already favorited ; 2. There is a common trait between the tweets that raise this exception (my first though is that it could be related to the retweets).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.